# NSIS relative directory to absolute

Tags: directory, nsis, relative-path, absolute-path

In NSIS I need to convert path, that contains relative part to absolute
without **"..\"** or **"../"** .
For example:

```
StrCpy $0 "C:\Windows\System"
StrCpy $1 "$0\..\"
```

I need some function to return **"C:\Windows"** in this case

Answer (score 3):

After some more searching I found build-in NSIS function

```
GetFullPathName output input
```

http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Reference/GetFullPathName

Answer (score 0):

There is a function to do this:

http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Function_that_makes_absolute_paths_from_relative_ones

Comment: Tried this one, but did not understand how to get the result